# Deprecate old name for class in C++

Tags: c++, macros, typedef, c-preprocessor, deprecated

I work on a framework that has massively renamed all its classes and functions, I created a transition header allowing to use old names:

```
#define OldClassA NewClassA
#define OldClassB NewClassB
...
```

Now I would like the compiler to warn the user when the old name is used. How can I do this?

```
int main(){
  NewClassA newA;
  OldClassA oldA; // <-- This one would emit a warning
}
```

Comment: Temporary fix: `__attribute__((deprecated)) class OldClass: public NewClass {};`

Comment: Don't use `#define` to provide aliases, this is unsafe. Use `typedef` instead.

Comment: @syam: pure curiosity, but could you give an example where it's not *safe*?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Once your users figure out that the reason they've been tearing their hair out for hours is because your scope-less `#define` has messed up a part of their code totally unrelated to yours, they're gonna *hunt* you, and do you bodily harm if they ever catch you. Definitely unsafe, both for your users' code and for your own health... ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It's also unsafe because any old idiot can just `#undef OldClassA` and `#define OldClassA MaliciousClassA`. `typedef` and `using` can only be done once and can't be undone.

Comment: @syam: the `typedef` will also mess up their code.

Comment: @Pharap: too contrived for me.. tried to come up with a real-life scenario but couldn't. Why would you work with an idiot? And if he abuses it for his own fun, how is that my problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As said by others, this is very compiler specific. Assuming your classes are defined with the new name. Here is what you can do with GCC and MSVC:

```
class NewClassA {}; // Notice the use of the new name.

// Instead of a #define, use a typedef with a deprecated atribute:

// MSVC
typedef NewClassA __declspec(deprecated) OldClassA;

// GCC
//typedef NewClassA __attribute__((deprecated)) OldClassA;

int main(){
    NewClassA newA;
    OldClassA oldA;
}
```

MSVC yields:

> > warning C4996: 'OldClassA': was declared deprecated

GCC yields:

> > warning: 'OldClassA' is deprecated

No warning is emmited for `NewClassA newA;` by either compiler.

Answer (score 8):

This is likely highly compiler specific.

For GCC, the reference page at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html describes the `deprecated` attribute and has examples for `typedef`s which I think should suit your needs:

```
typedef NewClassA OldClassA __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

Clang has somethign similar, see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

For Visual C++, you could try its `deprecated` declaraton/pragma: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Since the release of C++14, you can now use the `[[deprecated]]` attribute, independent of the compiler (so long as the compiler
fully supports C++14, of course).

In your case, you would use:

```
[[deprecated]]
typedef NewClassA OldClassA;

// You can also include a message that will show up in the compiler
// warning if the old name is used:

[[deprecated("OldClassA is deprecated; use NewClassA instead.")]]
typedef NewClassA OldClassA;
```

Note that this is only supported in gcc-4.9 (if using gcc) and you will need to specify `-std=c++1y`. I do not know about MSVC; clang supports this as of version 3.4.

See http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/marking-deprecated-c++14.html for more details on how to deprecate things other than just typedefs.

Answer (score 1):

Many compilers support `#warning` directive. E.g. VS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266053(v=vs.60).aspx or GCC:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html

`#warning "old class name is used"`. Or in C++11 you can use `static_assert`.

Something like this:

```
#ifdef OldClassA
   #warning "old class name is used"
```

Comment: Yes but can you use the warning macro inside a #define ? For example: #define OldClassA #warning ("......") NewClassA

Comment: @azmeuk Can't you use `#ifdef`?

Comment: @azmeuk, *Technically*, you can do `#define OldClassA _Pragma("message .....")` in C++11. AFAIK, `#pragma message` is in the main three compilers. That kind of defeats the point, though, since there's `static_assert`.